# How to add Keycloak realm role to group via REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I want to assign the realm role "TEST_ROLE_123" to a group, I am using

```
PUT /admin/realms/ataccamaone/groups/{group-id}
{
"realmRoles":["TEST_ROLE_123"]
}
```

I got `group-id` from `/admin/realms/ataccamaone/groups/`

However I get the response `204 No Content` and in the Keycloak console I do not see the assignment.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to reproduce your problem and find that `PUT /admin/realms/ataccamaone/groups/{group-id}` can only edit group name.

Inspect into "Network" tab of browser, I see it uses another URL to map roles to groups. And steps to do this via Admin REST API are:

1. Obtain PAT as described in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_protection_whatis_obtain_pat section

Following steps use this PAT as Bearer token (in "Authorization" header). I guess you've already got this.

2. Call `GET http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/realm1/roles` to get list of roles, including their `name` and `id` values.
3. Call `GET http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/realm1/groups` to get list of groups, including their `id`s
4. Call `POST http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/realm1/groups/{group-id}/role-mappings/realm` with following body:

   ```
   [
     {
       "id": "9083cac3-4280-497d-b973-7713a5fb12b4",  // role-id
       "name": "secretary"   // role-name
     }
   ]
   ```
5. Call `DELETE` with URL and body same as step 4 to remove roles from group.

Comment: Which credentials do we need to have to get authorization for this api?

Comment: 9 month later I'm running into the same issue. Keycloak is great in many ways but the documentation could really use its own project to bring it up a level.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. Keycloak docs could be improved on this topic...

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and corrected it with using a GROUP, Basically I've added the preferred ROLE into the User Groups ROLE LIST and used that specific user group while creating the user via REST API.

Eg:- ADMIN_USER_GROUP -> INCLUDED ('ADMIN_ROLE')

Then User creation API Request should be like below,

```
{
    "firstName": "Sergey",
    "lastName": "Kargopolov",
    "email": "test4@test.com",
    "enabled": "true",
    "credentials": [
        {
            "value": "123"
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        "ADMIN_USER_GROUP"
    ]
}
```